# Generate a list of hex bytes in Python

Tags: python, hex, byte, ascii

I want to generate a list of the hex values of all 256 byte-combinations.

Basically, I want for example 'A' => '\x41'. I've only found modules capable of converting 'A' => '41', and this is not what I want.

How am I to solve this problem? Does anybody know an appropriate module or algorithm (as I'd like to avoid hardcoding 256 hexvalues...)?

Comment: ASCII actually only has 128 values - do you mean ASCII or "fits in 8 bits"? For that matter, do you want only printable characters?

Comment: Why would you want to put it back into a string? `'\x41'` is equivalent to `'A'` (try it). Or do you want the string literal `r'\x41'`?

Comment: "I've only found modules"?  Which ones?  That doesn't seem sensible.  Perhaps you mean functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> hex(ord('A'))
'0x41'
```

Is that the kind of thing you want?

Maybe something like this?

```
for o in range(128):
    print chr(o), hex(o)
```

Or maybe

```
import string
for c in string.printable:
    print c, hex(ord(c))
```

Answer (score 1):

`ord('A')` returns the ASCII value as an integer (65 in the case of 'A'). You can think of an integer in any base you want. `hex(ord('A'))` gives you a nice string ("0x41" in this case), as does `print "%x" % ord('A')`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to print `b'\x00'` all the way to `b'\xff'`? If so then my assumption is that the best answer should contain a range of 256

```
for o in range(256):
    print(hex(o))
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the numeric value of each ASCII upper and lower case letter as a list:

```
from string import ascii_letters
[ord(c) for c in ascii_letters]
```

Answer (score 0):

so, you found the way of doing for one char, lets just do it for all of them in a loop or list comprehension.
`[(chr(x), '%x' % x) for x in range(256)]`

this will create a list with (char, string with value in hex).
if you want the value display in some other way you can play around with the format string like

```
>>> 'x%02x' % ord('\r')
'x0d'
```